# How to use ball shading on non-circle shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

If using ball shading on non-circle elements, it will well apply the shading effect, but it will use the default blue color. How to use ball shading with the element color.

```
\node[text width=3cm,fill=red,shading=ball] (test) at (1,1) {Text};
```

This will produce a rectangle with ball shading effect; however, in **blue** color instead of **red**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the `ball color` option:

```
\node[text width=3cm, shading=ball, ball color=red] (test) at (1,1) {Text};
```

More details in the `PGF/TikZ` manual (v 2.10) - page 413, under `/tikz/ball color`, where you can find links to other sections with other useful options too.

Comment: Thanks, I check TikZ manual everyday for my issues; but it is not easy to find something in 800 pages ;)